# Missing character: There is no c in font msbm10!

Tags: symbols

Let $\mathbb{c}={c_1,\ldots,c_K}$
it cannot be displayed on the page

Comment: Try using a capital "C"

Comment: Generally the bb and cal setup only supports uppercase letters. Very few fonts offer them in lower case.

Comment: I understand, it does not support lowercase letters. It seems that I need to change the representation method